# Grails 3, change contextPath dynamically (servletContext?)

Tags: servlets, grails, grails-3.0, contextpath

I have a problem changing the contextPath of an grails 3 web application dynamically. It's working if I change it in groovy.gsp (server.contextPath = "/myApp"), but i need to deploy it with different names like that:

```
myApp_A.war         =>  IP:Port/myApp_A
myApp_B.war         =>  IP:Port/myApp_B
```

In can get the direcory name (llike: "myApp_A" for myApp_A.war) and read the right properties file dynamically (myApp_A.properties). After that I'm trying to set the context path for this instance dynamically to IP:Port/myApp_A

I tried to change the grails "server.contextPath" in the bootstrap like this:

```
Holders.config.'server.contextPath' = '/myApp_A'
```

But this is not working completely. In this case I will be redirected to `IP:Port/myApp_A`, but then I got 404. The webservice is still listening to the static configurartion ("/myApp").

I think I have to change it earlier (in bootstrap it's too late), or change it directly in the servletContext. After changing `Holders.config.'server.contextPath'` to the new path, the servletContext is still containing the old static path (`servletContext.getContextPath()`  = old path).

In:

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware { 
...
```

I can read my settings and inject them before the servletContext is created. Any ideas how I can set the contextPath there?

Regards,
grailsfan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In application.groovy, write your logic to set the context path.

You can set server.contextPath = "path_a".

So

```
if ( myCondition == true ) {
    server.contextPath = "path_a"
} else {
    server.contextPath = "path_b"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In application.yml add to each environment. Then when you build WAR for each environment you context changes too.

```
grails.serverURL: 'http://localhost:8080/myapp'
server:
  port: 8080
  contextPath: '/myapp'
```

Comment: OK, but then I would have to create a new build for every new tenant. (every different contextName)

Comment: Grails 3 uses Gradle to build. Combination of Gradle and Jenkins can make build easier for you. It would be some work to set it up. But it will make cleaner code